# Изменение текста

Tags: html, css

Привет всем! У меня есть шаблон на английском языке. Хочу переименовать один пункт меню в русский, но при переводе исчезает просто текст. Пробую латинскими символами - работает. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Шаблон на чём? CMS какая-то? Она русскоязычная?

Comment: Шаблон на css, html. Он не под CMS, простой.

Comment: @Александр Гижевский, че ?

Answer (score 2):

Проблема с кодировкой. Надо все файлы в шаблоне преобразовать в одну кодировку и в файле index.html (если у вас есть такой) прописать ту кодировку, в которую вы преобразовали файлы.

Comment: Какой программой нужно воспользоваться?

Comment: Notepad++ справляется через раз. Я пользуюсь phpDesigner

Answer (score 0):

Сначала убедитесь что у вас на странице есть следующая строка (пример для кодировки utf-8):

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='Type=text/html; charset=utf-8'>
```

Убедитесь, что сам файл сохранен в кодировке utf-8 (например через notepad++).
Убедитесь, что на Вашем сервере кодировка по умолчанию utf-8.
И наконец, на всякий случай, в самом браузере может быть явно указана другая кодировка.